# Time Capsule will not allow allow a guest network in Bridge mode. Why?

Tags: wifi, time-capsule, guest-account

My 2 terabyte Time Capsule used to allow a guest wifi network but since I had to switch to bridge mode to accommodate my cable internet provider (while installing an Exchange server w/o a static ip address) I no longer have the guest option.

Why?

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

When placing the Time Capsule in Bridge mode, you are turning off NAT, and IP operations.

The ability for guests to be able to get to the Internet but not be able to access the home network was a result of access rules that stated the IP range that supports the guest network are not allowed to talk to the other internal network.  It is possible to do such a thing using a technology known as private-VLANs, but I don't think the Time Capsule has that sophisticated of code.  So, when we put our router into bridge mode, we become one layer 2 ethernet bridged network - that is bridged to the Access Point - within one IP network.

There does not appear to be the code necessary to do layer 2 (ethernet/wireless ethernet) separation and security.  It is doable, but apparently not in the Time Capsule.

Answer (score 0):

The TimeCapsule allows enabling the Guest Network while in bridge mode, but because bridge mode disables all management services, the Time Capsule has no ability to offer any services for this second SSID such as DHCP —± connecting to the Guest SSID will get "No Internet" status on the client.

To address this issue, Apple tags all packets going to/from the Guest Network with the 802.11q VLAN tag ID 1003. This allows these packets to be treated separate from the default Primary VLAN ID of 1. On your main router you will need to create an allocation for VLAN ID 1003 t as well as ingress/egress rules for it.

Once the main router is configured to correctly handle packets tagged with VLAN 1003, it will correctly interpret the 802.11q VLAN tagged packets coming from the Time Capsule and be able to address them accordingly as their own virtual LAN, allowing access for devices connecting to the Guest WiFI SSID.

Answer (score -2):

There is a work around - check out:
https://www.thegeekpub.com/5191/use-airport-extreme-guest-network-bridge-mode/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.